# schedule k-1, 1041 form after taxes filed

Tags: united-states, taxes

Hi i just received a form 1041 dated April 5th but post marked may first. It was well after taxes have been filed:

- Line 1 - a-102.
- Line 2a-c 111.
- Line 2b-d 2366.

Do I need to file an amendment?

Answer (score 1):

The IRS has a FAQ: [Amended Returns & Form 1040X][irs1

> **What should I do if I made a mistake on my federal return that I've already filed?**
>
> Answer:
>
> It depends on the type of mistake you made:
>
> - Many mathematical errors are caught during the processing of the tax return and corrected by the IRS, so you may not need to correct
>   these mistakes.
> - If you didn't claim the correct filing status or you need to change your income, deductions, or credits, you should file an amended or
>   corrected return using Form 1040-X,  Amended U.S. Individual Income
>   Tax Return.

They even have a tool: [Should I File an Amended Return?](https://www.irs.gov/help/ita/should-i-file-an-amended-return)

So if the K-1 changes your income, then you will have to file an amended return.